# Access BIOS from an external monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, bios, hdmi, external-display

Laptop display is not working properly. It is showing a white screen when turn on. I need to access **BIOS** of this laptop.

What I have **tried** so far and **failed**:

- Set project settings as "Secondary Screen Only".
- Set when lid close value in power option as "Do Nothing".
- Connect to an external monitor using HDMI.
- Connect to an external monitor using VGA port.

The laptop is Lenovo G510 i5. OS is Windows 10 Home.

How could I achieve this **without** disconnecting the laptop screen cable from motherboard?

Comment: Laptops typically have a button that allows you to switch between its own screen and the external display. According to the manual for a lenovo G510 (https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g400g500g405g505g410g510_ug_english.pdf page 5), this is the F10 key. So once you boot, press the key to get into bios and then press F10 or FN+F10 to switch to the external monitor.

Comment: @Silbee Thanks for the reply. But this method didn't work.

Comment: Some laptops will output bios on external display, some will not. What size is the external monitor?

Comment: @Moab is on the money here.  Some do.. some don't.  Some mirror the display to the external (on boot), some force external only, some don't do anything..  it is up to whoever wrote the UEFI firmware.

Comment: @Moab 24". It's a Dell S2421HN